What is "inactive status for cause"?
What is "inactive status for cause"?

I was asked the following question on a job application,

Were you ever put on inactive status for cause, or subjected to disciplinary action (including but not limited to reprimand, suspension or demotion) while with any employer or organization?


uh... suspension?

Yup. Has an employer ever suspended you for any valid reason?

Seems like a better fit for Workplace SE.
